# Convert OpenCV Python code to Java code for Border/Stroke/Outline to Transparent PNG

Tags: java, python, android, opencv

I have following OpenCV code from python, which I am trying to convert in java code, but I stuck on few lines and I cant able to convert this complete code. I don't have any option because no source available related java for the requirement.

```
def stroke(origin_image, threshold, stroke_size, colors):
    img = np.array(origin_image)
    h, w, _ = img.shape
    padding = stroke_size + 50
    alpha = img[:,:,3]
    rgb_img = img[:,:,0:3]
    bigger_img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(rgb_img, padding, padding, padding, padding, 
                                    cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(0, 0, 0, 0))
    alpha = cv2.copyMakeBorder(alpha, padding, padding, padding, padding, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 
    value=0)
    bigger_img = cv2.merge((bigger_img, alpha))
    h, w, _ = bigger_img.shape

    _, alpha_without_shadow = cv2.threshold(alpha, threshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  
    alpha_without_shadow = 255 - alpha_without_shadow
    dist = cv2.distanceTransform(alpha_without_shadow, cv2.DIST_L2, cv2.DIST_MASK_3)  
    stroked = change_matrix(dist, stroke_size)
    stroke_alpha = (stroked * 255).astype(np.uint8)

    stroke_b = np.full((h, w), colors[0][2], np.uint8)
    stroke_g = np.full((h, w), colors[0][1], np.uint8)
    stroke_r = np.full((h, w), colors[0][0], np.uint8)

    stroke = cv2.merge((stroke_b, stroke_g, stroke_r, stroke_alpha))
    stroke = cv2pil(stroke)
    bigger_img = cv2pil(bigger_img)
    result = Image.alpha_composite(stroke, bigger_img)
    return result

def change_matrix(input_mat, stroke_size){
    stroke_size = stroke_size - 1
    mat = np.ones(input_mat.shape)
    check_size = stroke_size + 1.0
    mat[input_mat > check_size] = 0
    border = (input_mat > stroke_size) & (input_mat <= check_size)
    mat[border] = 1.0 - (input_mat[border] - stroke_size)
    return mat
}

def cv2pil(cv_img){
   cv_img = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA)
   pil_img = Image.fromarray(cv_img.astype("uint8"))
   return pil_img
}


output = stroke(test_image, threshold=0, stroke_size=10, colors=((0,0,0),))
```

I have problem with bellow code. I cant able to convert this code to java code.

```
def change_matrix(input_mat, stroke_size){
    stroke_size = stroke_size - 1
    mat = np.ones(input_mat.shape)
    check_size = stroke_size + 1.0
    mat[input_mat > check_size] = 0
    border = (input_mat > stroke_size) & (input_mat <= check_size)
    mat[border] = 1.0 - (input_mat[border] - stroke_size)
    return mat
}
```